# how to tell if a program has been successfully parallelized?

Tags: parallel-processing

A program run on a parallel machine is measured to have the following efficiency values for increasing numbers of processors, P.

```
P 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
E 100 90 85 80 70 60 50
```

Using the above results, plot the speedup graph.

Use the graph to explain whether or not the program has been successfully parallelized.

```
P E    Speedup
1 100% 1
2  90% 1.8
3  85% 2.55
4  80% 3.2
5  70% 3.5
6  60% 3.6
7  50% 3.5
```

This is a past year exam question, and I know how to calculate the speedup & plot the graph. However I don't know how to tell a program is successfully parallelized.

Comment: We frown upon copy-pasted homework assignment / exam questions. Please rewrite to first person, then we'll talk.

Comment: Did you cover [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) in your course ?

Comment: OK - so you might want to read the Wikipedia page linked to in my comment then.

Comment: @PaulR thanks paul, please help to check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

```
I think the idea here is that not all portion can be parallelized.
```

For example, if a program needs 20 hours using a single processor core, and ***a particular portion of 1 hour cannot be parallelized***, while the remaining promising portion of 19 hours (95%) can be parallelized, then regardless of how many processors we devote to a parallelized execution of this program, the minimum execution time cannot be less than that critical 1 hour. Hence the speedup is limited up to 20×

[image]

In this example, the speedup reached maximum 3.6 with 6 processors. So the parallel portion is about 1-1/3.6 is about 72.2%.